# How to check return status of parallel branches in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, groovy

I am running a Jenkins job on multiple slaves. Following is the code structure:

```
def branches = [:]
def allNodes = Jenkins.getInstance().getNodes()
for (int i =0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
branches[allNodes[i].name.toString()] = {
    node(allNodes[i].name.toString()) { 
    .
    .
    stuff
    }
}
parallel branches
```

Now, I want to get the status of the job parts running on nodes so that in case some job part fails on some node I can mark that node as offline. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I tried storing the slave job part status in a file and stashing it on node and then unstashing it back on master. It works but I am looking for a cleaner way. Following is the current approach i am using:

```
def branches = [:]
def allNodes = Jenkins.getInstance().getNodes()
for (int i =0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
String nodeName = allNodes[i].name.toString()
branches[nodeName] = {
    node(nodeName) { 
    .
    .
    String outputFile = nodeName + "-output"
    writeFile file: outputFile, text: result.toString()
    stash includes: "*output", name: outputFile
    }
}
parallel branches

for (int i = 0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) 
{
    String filename = allNodes[i].name.toString() + "-output"
    unstash filename
    def value = readFile filename

    // Mark node offline based on the variable value
}
```

Comment: using this as well. hope will find a cleaner way, too.

Comment: Nothing changed in 2024

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the [Join plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin). Some more details about this plugin (from the linked page):

> This plugin allows a job to be run after all the immediate downstream jobs have completed. In this way, the execution can branch out and perform many steps in parallel, and then run a final aggregation step just once after all the parallel work is finished.
>
> The plugin is useful for creating a 'diamond' shape project dependency.   This means there is a single parent job that starts several downstream jobs. Once those jobs are finished, a single aggregation job runs.

For more details on that, refer to my self answered question about "[Why trigger something remotely (using Jenkins) and then just forget about it?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/717/40)".

Comment: IMHO the mentioned plugin designed fir chaining jobs not for parallel pipeline steps